# SendKeys Method in Powershell

Tags: powershell, telnet

I have batch file for telnet a server automatically, I want to do the same thing with PowerShell

Batch File named Script.bat :

```
:: Open a Telnet window
 start telnet.exe 10.84.10.85
:: Run the script
 cscript SendKeys.vbs
```

Command File named SendKeys.vbs :

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "myPassword{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "7{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "1{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 1000
 OBJECT.SendKeys "Y{ENTER}"
 WScript.sleep 3000
 OBJECT.SendKeys ""
```

Comment: `start-process path\telnet.exe -argumentlist 10.84.10.85` to start telnet, `$obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell` to create the object, `$obj.SendKeys("x")` to send the keys, `sleep -ms 1000`to sleep

Comment: that's what I'm looking for exact !! merci :)

Comment: @SimonS please make an aswer from  your comment.

Comment: Just chiming into what others give you. Avoid COM at all costs, unless there is no other choice. Use the offered up .Net namespace as your default.  This `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")`, in PowerShell is really legacy stuff. The current way is via the Add-Type cmdlet. `Add-Type -AssemblyName  Microsoft.VisualBasic, PresentationCore`. SendKeys has gotcha's, so, really look at stuff like [`AutoIT`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+autoit%27&t=h_&ia=web) and `Selenium` for this kind of thing.

Comment: @postanote What kind of "gotchas" are you talking about? Any links or refs?

Comment: @not2qubit - It's all about how SendKeys work. Its performance is directly impacted by the environment in which it is executed. Just because it runs as expected on your machine or another, does not mean in will perform as expected on other systems. There are many articles on the topic. ['why sendkeys is problematic'](https://duckduckgo.com/?va=v&t=ha&q=%27why+sendkeys+is+problematic%27&ia=web)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PowerShell has no built-in functionality to emulate keystrokes.

Practically, you have two options: COM-Automation and Interop.

1. SendKeys via COM

Like in VB(S) you can create a Shell-Object and SendKeys. Here is the PowerShell way to do it.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys('a')
```

If you would like to send a keystroke to a window, you have to activate it first:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

Some keystrokes have special variables like ~ for RETURN. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx) is a complete list.
After activating a window it's often necessary to wait a second until it becomes responsive, otherwise it'll send the key to the PowerShell window, or to nowhere.
The scripting Host's SendKeys method can be unreliable, but luckily there is a better approach.

2. SendKeys via Interop

Like in C#, you can use the [SendWait](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx) method from the .NET Framework in PowerShell.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("x")
```

If you want to activate a window, it can be done like this:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Internet Explorer - Windows")
```

To Sleep, you can use the [Start-Sleep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731014.aspx) Cmdlet.

Regarding your original problem, I would suggest the following solution:

```
# Open a Telnet window
Start-Process telnet.exe -ArgumentList 10.84.10.85
# Run the keystrokes
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('myPassword{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('7{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('1{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('Y{ENTER}')
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('')
```

WARNING: Be extra careful if you're using this method to send a password because activating a different window between invoking `AppActivate` and invoking `SendKeys` will cause the password to be sent to that different window in plain text (e.g. your favorite messenger)!

Comment: "PowerShell has no built-in functionality to emulate keystrokes." - just import Windows-DLLs and call API?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan This seems to be still true. https://www.powershellgallery.com/ also has no suitable Cmdlet to send keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

```
function Do-SendKeys {
    param (
        $SENDKEYS,
        $WINDOWTITLE
    )
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    IF ($WINDOWTITLE) {$wshell.AppActivate($WINDOWTITLE)}
    Sleep 1
    IF ($SENDKEYS) {$wshell.SendKeys($SENDKEYS)}
}
Do-SendKeys -WINDOWTITLE Print -SENDKEYS '{TAB}{TAB}'
Do-SendKeys -WINDOWTITLE Print
Do-SendKeys -SENDKEYS '%{f4}'
```

Comment: Short, simple, versatile -- for those systems where `$wshell.SendKeys` works. See wp78de answer for the `Interop` alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I did some of modification in the script, I have a list of IP server which have the same password and I want to telnet the list automatically and sendKey for deactivate or activate the FTP server .

my script is :

```
  ## - List of IP
  $printers = get-content "C:\Dir2\servers.txt"

  foreach ($IPAddress in $printers){

   ## - Start Telnet Session:
     start-process C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe -argumentlist $IPAddress

   ## - SendKey for each IP
     $obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("MyPassword{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("7{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("1{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("Y{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     $obj.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
     sleep -s 3
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will run SendKeys and clean up the COM object when it's done. It's not perfect, but it works.

The -Delay parameter gives you some time to switch focus to another application before it sends the keys.

```
function Send-Keystrokes ([string] $Keys, [int] $Delay = 0)
{
    try
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Delay
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $wshell.SendKeys($Keys)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$wshell) | Out-Null
            [System.GC]::Collect()
            [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cleanup isn't necessary. When .NET GC's a wrapped COM object, it will call Release. In PS, calling `Remove-Variable` is adequate.