# Start google chrome's task manager from command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

Is there any way to start google chrome's task manager from command line?

(In fact, I'm even having trouble identifying the process associated with the task manager popup. For instance, I can kill every chrome.exe process except for the gpu-process and utility, neither of which are the task manager pop-up, with the chrome task manager unaffected.)

Comment: You probably need more then a command line to do this, I’m not 100% sure about some command line capable to do this task..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you really need more than the command line.

Try this hybrid script with cmd/bat and vbs, use SendKeys to send Shift+Esc to call the Task Manager in the Chrome interface.

```bat
<!-- :
@echo off
"%windir%\system32\wScript.exe" "%~dpnx0?.wsf" & goto :EOF
:: --> 
<job> 
<script language = "vbscript"> 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "Chrome.exe", 9
WScript.Sleep 700
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "+{ESC}"
</script>
</job>
```

- You can also use SendKey in Powershell ...

```bat
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Run('Chrome'),9
Start-Sleep -m 700
$obj.SendKeys("+{ESC}")
```

- **[Hybrid VBS/Bat Files](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html)**
- **[SendKeys Method in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell/1250038)**
- **[WSF - Windows Script File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File)**
- **[SendKeys Method in VBScript](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**
- **[Execute Hybrid Bat/Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)**