# On a Windows machine, without downloading anything, how can I create a keybinding to paste without whitespace?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

My friend's workflow requires copying and pasting of numbers many times per day, however the numbers to be copied are rendered with spaces and the locations to paste require there to be no spaces.

Also, the company will not allow employees to download anything extra (so we can't use AutoHotKey, for example).

That said, I believe it *must* be possible to do this within the constraints. Maybe with Powershell?

How can we create a keybinding that will paste the clipboard's contents *without* whitespaces?

Comment: Powershell can be made to [send keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell) with a little work so you could [get the clipboard contents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7.2), [trim the whitespace](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-trim/) and then "type" it out. I don't know how you would assign your powershell script to a hotkey though.

Comment: What is the source application where the numbers originate (eg, web page)?  What is the target application (eg, MS Excel)?  PowerShell is likely fully capable for this task, but there could be more streamlined options available dependending upon your app requirements.  If you choose PowerShell, you can create a Windows shortcut to your script, then assign a shortkey key to that Windows shortcut.

Comment: The source and target are both Google Chrome. I found a Chrome extension that can accept a custom javascript function and I think this will work, however it requires my friend to right-click instead of using ctrl+c. Not ideal, but much better!

Thank you for the tips on PowerShell! We will try that too.