# pass Keystroke to powershell in background, started with -w hidden

Tags: powershell, script, background, keystrokes

I am trying to learn powershell scripting and I have the following problem:

A script needs to get a ENTER keystroke during its runtime so the first lines are executed before the 2nd part starts. The script is started with "powershell -w hidden script.ps1" so it is running in background with no window visible.

How can I achieve that? I did not find an answer that I can understand. Is it possible to write a keystroke in the script somehow?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are a few different ways that a powershell script can ask for input, so you'll have to add some more details. Typically you would suppress the request with something like `-confirm:$false` or `-force`. If you do need to send a specific key press, then take a look at the options here: https://superuser.com/a/1250038/673426