# Is it possible to control browser video playback with key macro and not lose focus from current program?

Tags: video, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

Here's my scenario: I've got a gamedev.tv (or youtube, whatever) page open on one screen playing a tutorial video. On my other screen is Blender or Unity, whatever it is I'm learning.

I need to pause, rewind 10s, play, etc but I don't want my browser to grab focus. I can move my mouse over to pause, etc, but sometimes (ok, many times) I forget to click back in the program and press a key (this is mostly blender which is key shortcut heavy) in the browser instead of the program.

I thought about programming some keys on my old Logitech G13 but its just a keyboard and (afaik) can't be told to only send keys to a particular program.

Is there a simple remote control that could do this?

Comment: Y0u can use Windows Script SendKeys() method to send the appropriate keys to pause, rewind, etc. See https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell .

Comment: @DrMoishePippik awesome thanks!