# Wrote a powershell script in Windows 10. Powershell closes immediately when I run it on Windows 11

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script to prevent the screen from locking by toggling scroll lock every few minutes. I originally wrote it in Windows 10, and it was working fine (right click -> run in power shell).

I have then upgraded to Win 11, and the script no longer works when I run it via right click -> run in Powershell. Powershell (terminal) will open for a split second, then close itself.

The script is:

```
Echo "dont sleep"

$WShell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"

while ($true){
   $WShell.sendkeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
   Echo "beep"
   $WShell.sendkeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 240
   Echo "boop"
}
```

Comment: Could it be that Wscript.Shell is not installed? There is another way of sending keys with `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait()` shown in [SendKeys Method in Powershell](https://superuser.com/a/1250038/272824).

Comment: Have you bothered to run it from a console so you can actually see what the resulting error says?  I bet the comment you see from @AndrewMorton will point you in the right direction but indeed.. if you are going to run and debug scripts, don't do it from a right-click.

Comment: Please provide your PowerShell profile settings for each system.

Comment: Is this the only script that shows this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Comment: What was your execution policy before? And what scope did you change to RemoteSigned (there are several scopes)?